# Selecting indices for a 2d array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

This works quite well in 1 dimension:

```
# This will sort bar by the order of the values in foo
(Pdb) bar = np.array([1,2,3])
(Pdb) foo = np.array([5,4,6])
(Pdb) bar[np.argsort(foo)]
array([2, 1, 3])
```

But how do I do that in two dimensions?  Argsort works nicely, but the select no longer works:

```
(Pdb) foo = np.array([[5,4,6], [9,8,7]])
(Pdb) bar = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
(Pdb)  bar[np.argsort(foo)]
*** IndexError: index (2) out of range (0<=index<=1) in dimension 0
(Pdb)
```

I would expect this to output:

```
array([[2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 1]])
```

Any clue how to do it?

Thanks!
/YGA

Edit: `take()` would seem to do the right thing, but it really only takes elements from the first row (super confusing).

You can see that if I change the values of bar:

```
(Pdb) bar = np.array([["1","2","3"], ["A", "B", "C"]])
(Pdb) bar.take(np.argsort(foo))
array([['2', '1', '3'],
       ['3', '2', '1']], 
      dtype='|S1')
(Pdb)
```

Comment: `bar[[[0],[1]], np.argsort(foo)]` seems to do what you want, though.

Comment: @Alok: yes, but the strategy seemed to fail on a more complicated example (I also have to say I find it somewhat cryptic).

Comment: @YGA: Can you tell us what the complicated example is?  I will explain the method in more detail later today, if you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar.take(np.argsort(foo))` produced your desired output, so you should take a look at its [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) to make sure it actually does what you think you want.

Edit:

Try this: `bar.take(np.argsort(foo.ravel()).reshape(foo.shape))`

Comment: (tried to add a comment, but it was misformatted because you can't have code in comments.  See edit above)

Comment: Right you are - it takes based on the flattened dimensions, and 0, 1, and 2 all lie in the first row of that array. Here, this might work...

Comment: Does not work, always gives the 1st row of `bar` re-ordered differently.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
bar[[[0],[1]], np.argsort(foo)]
```

This is because you need two indices to index `bar`.  The `[[0], [1]]` is to get correct broadcasting.  See [this post on numpy-discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-February/040128.html) mailing list for exactly the same question and the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A nice generic solution (with n rows to sort) is offered [at this post](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-April/049949.html), i.e.,

```
bar[np.arange(foo.shape[0])[:,None], np.argsort(foo)]
```