# Manipulating indices to 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, multidimensional-array

I can index a 2d numpy array with a tuple or even a list of tuples

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
i = [(0,1),(1,0)] # edit: bad example, should have taken [(0,1),(0,1)]
print a[i[0]], a[i]
```

(Gives `2 [2 3]`)

However, I can not manipulate the tuples with vector arithmetic, i.e.

```
k = i[0]+i[1]
```

does not give the desired `(1,1)` but concatenates.

On the other hand using numpy arrays for the indices, the arithmetic works, but the indexing does not work.

```
i = numpy.array(i)
k = i[0]+i[1]      # ok
print a[k]
```

gives the array `[[3 4], [3 4]]` instead of the desired `4`.

**Is there a way** to **do vector arithmetic on the indices** but also be able **to** index a **numpy array** with them (without deriving a class from tuple and overloading all the operators)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016842/selecting-indices-for-a-2d-array-in-numpy) looked promising at first but I could not figure out if I can apply it to my situation.

Edit (comment on accepted answer):

... and working on arrays of indices then works as well using map

```
arr = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
ids = numpy.array([(0,1),(1,0)])
ids += (0,1) # shift all indices by 1 column
print arr[map(tuple,ids.T)]
```

(confusing to me why I need the transpose, though.
Would have run into this problem above as well,
and was just fortunate with [(0,1),(0,1)])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Convert the NumPy array to a tuple when you need to index:

```
a[tuple(k)]
```

Test:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> i = numpy.array([(0,1),(1,0)])
>>> k = i[0] + i[1]
>>> a[tuple(k)]
4
```

Comment: +1 ah simple, should have thought of this myself! That would give may `tuple` in my code, but I will use it for now and if it get too many `tuple` I can still derive a class of my own in the end

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most straightforward way to do this would be to create a subclass of tuple and redefine its `__add__` operator to do what you want.  Here is how to do that: [Python element-wise tuple operations like sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497885/python-tuple-operations)

Comment: see my question (in the brackets before the question mark). Adding was just an example I'd need `__add__` `__sub__` `__mul__` `__rmul__` `__div__` and each for scalar/vector and vector/vector. Maybe such a class would be a nice extension for a future version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

try the following, it works for me:

```
import numpy

def functioncarla(a,b):
    return a+b

a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
i = [(0,1),(1,0)]

#k = i[0]+i[1]
aux = map(functioncarla, i[0], i[1])
k = tuple(aux)
print 'k = ', k

print 'a[k] = ', a[k]
```